# Bisection of a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

If we have one random triangle and bisected with respect to the longest edge, i.e [image]

Left the initial triangle with the longest edge is highlighted by double line. If we bisected this triangle, then we get the right. My question is: the longest edge of the two new triangles are the edges of picture with double line? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You can always construct a triangle with the biggest side c at least 2 times greater than one of the others two. Consider a triangle with sides 4, 10, 7.

Comment: If we have triangle with sides 3,4 and 5. Which side is at least twice than other?

Comment: There is no such in the case 3, 4, 5. However, if your triangle is with sides 2,4,5 (the triangle exists) then 5 is 2.5 more than 2.

Comment: But right angle triangle exist with sides 3,4 and 5.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't mention in your question that you want your triangle to be right..

Comment: Consider then the *right* triangle with sides 5, 12, 13. And see for yourself.